# Insert space after each number in a numeric string

Tags: php

I have a numeric string

```
$str = 987654;
```

I need to insert a space after each number. Shall I use str_split? Since I don't know how long the string is, how do I **echo** it as:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4
```

It's probably basic, but my caffeine wore out...

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: `echo implode(' ', str_split($str));`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster did not attempt a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```html
$str = 987654;
$formatted_str = implode(' ',str_split($str ));
```

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? It actually does exactly what I need.